# MySQL - ODBC connect as a second user fails, Workbench and CLI connect works

Tags: mysql, database, odbc

A little background: first I installed connection to MySQL Server through SSH Tunnel and logged in as a "root" user. It connects via ODBC driver to a remote MySQL DB server. Now I want to create another user with certain privileges which will be enough for creating some reports.

I created a second user account "PBI", it works fine in Command Line Interface and Workbench, but when I try to connect via ODBC, the following message appears: [MySQL][ODBC 8.0 Driver] Access denied for user "PBI@localhost" (using password: YES) [HY000].

I have tried to change the user permissions with kinda "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO..."; double-checked the username and password; checked the host and port; checked the firewall settings.

Comment: Did you set the account up to be allowed to be used remotely (Domain)

Comment: I think no. Do you mean it needs to set up a connection for this new user via ssh to a remote server separately? I just added an account in Workbench.

Comment: No each account looks like `me@locahost` or `me@127.0.0.1` thats a `userid@domain` so if it says `locahost` that account can only login from the PC which is running the instance of MySQL. So you would need something like `ivan@%` so you can login as ivan from any IP Address

Comment: Better still set it up as `ivan@111.222.333.444` where that the WAN ip address of your router. Then only you can login using that account from your home, for example

Comment: Ok, thank you. In the CLI username looks like 'PBI'@'localhost'. I thought the problem is that only one user per localhost can connect via ODBC.

Comment: This is talking about the user account setup in the MySQL server itself, not on the CLI

Comment: I added in Workbench another user for my collegue and she is succesefully logging from her PC to the Server, creating db's, tables, etc. Thank you a lot, but I don't understand difference between adding account and setuping user account. And it seems to be working with my collegue, so I guess it's about the ODBC connection for two users from one workstation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is solved! Just re-established connections and sighned localhost everywhere.